# At which rate does the leader pool rotate?

Tags: stellaris

I noticed that the choices to pick from in the Stellaris leader pool seem to change from time to time.

What is the actual interval, when does it make sense to have a look at the possible "new recruits"?

Comment: When you hire a scientist, you only get one new scientist in the pool (replacing the one you hired).  The other two (or three) spots will not change.  I want to say that it's about 3 or 6 months of in-game time for all the spots to rotate out.

Comment: @tgharold you could extend your comment a bit and write an answer.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment you hire a leader, a new one is added to the pool to replace the one you just hire.

The rate of rotation is quite unclear. According to this [Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/281990/discussions/0/357285562494059370/) and personal experience, the leaders from the pool change after a certain amount of time. Some people seems to think it might be when they died from old age. However, this hypothesis would mean rotation of leader with increased lifespan would be slowed, and immortal leader would not rotate at all. A more plausible hypothesis, based on the [leader wiki page](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Leader), would be that leaders are changed at 50 years old.

You can also manually change a candidate for the cost of 50 influence. You just have to hire and fire him instantly.

Comment: I'm not sure leaders in the pool are removed when they die from old age. Otherwise, tech and benefits that extend leader life span would mean rotatin is extremely slow, and immortal leaders (robots, psionics) would never rotate, but I believe they still do. So, that part of the answer needs a more definitive source.

Comment: @Ellesedil I added another hypothesis. If you think some other sources or precisions could be added, I encourage you to edit the answer!

Comment: Well, right now, I can hire an adaptable governor that's age 53: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jJ2U.png There's also two age 50 governors in that pool as well (one of which is in that screenshot). So, while the Wiki sounds much closer to the answer, it doesn't seem 100% accurate.